# How to create horizontal menu in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, custom-controls, android-widget

I am working on horizontal menu that will open on top of the screen.
Layout is something like following,

|| < || Menu Item1 || Menu Item2 || Menu Item3 || > ||

I want to put this on top of the screen. It can have more than 3 menu
item and it can traverse through previous and next arrow.
I started with like this,

- RelativeLayout ( width - fill_parent)

  - Gallery View ( Here i appended adapter )

There is two problem,
- Gallery view contains the space before and after
- While scrolling its item gets selected

Though its not ideal solution for this. How can i build custom
component like this ?
Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a gallery, you can override the onFling behaviour if you want to say slow down the fling or ignore vertical fling etc.

To disable the space, there is a an api call `gallery.setSpacing()`...
To make the gallery not select when you are flinging use `gallery.setCallbackDuringFling(false)`

However, if all you want is a static menu that scrolls with the left and right buttons, I'd just subclass a LinearLayout and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

After some time i figured out other way. It worked for me perfectly.

```
HorizontalScrollView
         - LinearLayout (orientation: Hoz)
            - LinearLayout - Menuitem1 (orientation: Verticle)
                   - ImageView
                   - TextView
            - LinearLayout - Menuitem2 (orientation: Verticle)
                   - ImageView
                   - TextView
            - LinearLayout - Menuitem3 (orientation: Verticle)
                   - ImageView
                   - TextView
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use ViewFlipper or HorizontalScrollView. No subclassing needed for those.