# how to create a menu with items come horizontally

Tags: android, menu

I create a menu in android I get result as below when I click on Menu button in emulator

the items are coming vertically stacked over each other , how can I make them horizontally

[image: menu]

Comment: change os version to 2.x ... thats how menu looks on 4.x

Comment: If you really want (it will be more work), you can create a custom menu xml and reference it in your onCreateOptionsMenu call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HorizontalScrollView in your layout and put your menu items in it. An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018155/horizontal-menu-with-horizontalscrollview-android), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832001/how-to-create-horizontal-menu-in-android)